# href is adding the url at the end of current url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Menu that is being populated from the database and coming in from my model to my view. The link that the menu is producing is correct. However, it is being appended to the end of my URL instead of replacing it.

```
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-        
haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" href="@menuLevel1.MenuLink">
                            @menuLevel1.MenuName                                
                        </a>

        in my DB Menulink="~/Admin/changepassword.aspx"
```

So when I click the button that is what I see 
http://localhost:51150/Mvc/Cats/~/Admin/changepassword.aspx
It is adding the url to end after the current url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url.Content is used when you wish to resolve a url for any file or resource on your site and you would pass it the relative path:

```
@Url.Content("~/path/file.htm")
```

Url.Action is used to resolve an action from a controller such as:

```
@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { variable = value })
```

you will have to add the action in your controller :

```
public YourControllerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult YourAction() { /* stuff */ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
href="@menuLevel1.MenuLink"
```

To

```
href="@Url.Content(menuLevel1.MenuLink)"
```

Comment: Did not work, getting Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: contentPath

Comment: Is it possible your cache is broken?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the links were null, thats why i was getting error now it is working. thanks Steve Harris.

```
@if (menuLevel2.MenuLink != null && menuLevel2.MenuLink != "")
                                        {
                                            <a href="@Url.Content(menuLevel2.MenuLink)">
                                                @menuLevel2.MenuName
                                            </a>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <a href="~/Homepage.aspx">
                                                @menuLevel2.MenuName
                                            </a>
                                        }
```

Comment: You could clean up the if statement a little by using string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuLevel2.MenuLink)